# MySQL: Unable to add an existing user to another Database?

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I am trying to add an existing user to another database but I am keep getting the error:

```
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

I tried the following, none worked:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

```
GRANT ALL  ON db.* TO 'user';
```

I am using MySQL on digitalocean

MySQL version: `8.0.31-0ubuntu2`

**Update**: I am using `root` user.

[image]

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS;` report when you are logged in as your own user? You may not have sufficient privileges to `GRANT ALL` on any database, if you don't have `ALL` privileges yourself.

Comment: @BillKarwin I updated question. I was logging as a root user.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/how-to-grant-privileges-to-users-in-mysql-80), it is not possible to create a user from the GRANT command in mysql 8:

> To start, let’s highlight the fact that in MySQL 8.0 it’s not any more possible to create a user directly from the GRANT command:

It states you have to create a user first, before granting privileges. Have you created the user first? If not, try that!

Comment: The user already exist and have rights of a db. I want to give rights of another newly created db

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user 1st. Follow the below steps.

1. `CREATE USER 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH authentication_plugin BY 'password';`
   or `CREATE USER 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` if the 1st command throws an error.
2. Grant privilege. `GRANT PRIVILEGE ON database.table TO 'username'@'host';`
3. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

You can find the full reference in [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

Comment: The user already exist